# dynamic array variable with dynamic values

Tags: php, arrays

I am in too much trouble. I need below type of array:-

```
$val = "abc";

$arr1["besk"] = $val
$arr2["besk"] = $val
     .    
     .
$arr15["besk"] = $val
```

I tried below:-

```
for($i = 1; $i<16; $i++)
{
   $arr.$i["besk"] = $val
}
```

here I've **$val**. so not to worry on that. But array is not properly creating. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you don't mind kindly explain what is $var and val in your program.

Comment: and also updated your expected output for this program.

Comment: @kmgkumar check my edited question.

Comment: _"I need below type of array"_ - no, more likely you just _think_ that you do ... "numbered" variables names are almost always a sign that you should use an array in that place instead.

Comment: @Everybody Thanks for great and quick answer. As everybody have same answer so not able to accept anybody's. Again Thanks for giving me all of Your valuable time.

Answer (score 3):

first define the array as string
like

`$arr = 'arr';`

then use the foreach
like

```
for($i = 1; $i<16; $i++)
  {
      ${$arr.$i}["besk"] = $val;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use variable variables (not recommended)

```
for($i = 1; $i<16; $i++)
{
    ${"arr".$i}["besk"] = $val
}
```

**EDIT** : @CBroe is right about his comment, you should use an array instead. So the best solution would be to create a two dimensional array like so :

```
$arr = [];
for($i = 0; $i<15; $i++)
{
    $arr[$i]["besk"] = $val
}
```

The only difference is your array indexes start from 0 now and if you want to have the third value of your array you need this command `$arr[2]["besk"]`

Answer (score 1):

it is very simple use this:

```
 for($i = 1; $i<16; $i++)
 {
      ${$arr.$i}["besk"] = $val
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this approach:

```html
for($i = 1; $i<16; $i++)
{
    ${$arr.$i}["besk"] = $val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add new variable

```
$val = "abc";
$arrName = "arr"; //this one
$arr1["besk"] = $val
$arr2["besk"] = $val
     .    
     .
$arr15["besk"] = $val
```

and to call it

```
for($i = 1; $i<16; $i++)
 {
      ${$arrName.$i}["besk"] = $val
 }
```

ps. you did not create array, you just create 15 array variable with 1 index("besk" index)